# Asynchronous function keeps reading old value of global variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I have the following React component

```
    const [prjToFetch, setPrjToFetch] = React.useState([]);

    React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Before " + prjToFetch)
    async function func(){
      let myPromise = await new Promise(function(myResolve, myReject) {
        setTimeout(function() { myResolve("I love You !!"); }, 3000);
      });

      
      console.log("After: " + prjToFetch)
      return myPromise;
    }

    func()
  }, [prjToFetch])
```

and I have a button that pushes the value "a" into the array prjFetch whenever it is pressed:

```
const handleClick = () => {
  setPrjToFetch([...prjToFetch, "a"]);
}
```

If I press the button once, the output of the previous code is:

```
Before a
(3 seconds of idle time)
After a
```

This is exactly what I expect. But let's suppose I press the button twice in a row, then the output is:

```
Before a
Before a a
(3 second of idle time)
After a
After a a
```

Why is the first "After" returning only "a" and not "a a"?

Notice that I also tried to rewrite the code as:

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Before " + prjToFetch)
    async function func(){
      await new Promise(function(myResolve, myReject) {
        setTimeout(function() { myResolve("I love You !!"); }, 3000);
      });
    }

    func().then(() => {
      console.log("After: " + prjToFetch)
    })
  }, [prjToFetch])
```

But the result is the same

Comment: *"Asynchronous function keeps reading old value of global variab;e"* The variable **isn't** global. If it were, you wouldn't see thsi behavior. (But you don't want it to be global.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `func` *closes over* the value of `prjToFetch` as of when `func` was created, and you're using that value *asynchronously*. By the time `func` uses the value, it's stale.

Here's what's happening:

1. The component mounts, triggering a call to your `useEffect` callback.

   1. That creates a copy of `func` that closes over the current `prjToFetch` variable.
   2. It calls that `func`
   3. That `func` starts waiting for three seconds
2. You click the button, triggering `prjToFetch`'s state setter
3. That makes the component function run again, **creating a new set of state variables**. Since `prjToFetch` has changed, React calls your `useEffect` callback again

   1. That creates a new `func` that closes over the new `prjToFetch` variable
   2. It calls that `func`
   3. That `func` starts waiting three seconds
4. The first `func` finishes waiting, and shows the value of the `prjToFetch` that it closes over
5. The second `func` finishes waiting, and shows the value of the `prjToFetch` that *it* closes over (which is not the same as the one the previous `func` closed over)

It's exactly the same as this:

```js
let aInComponentState = 1;
function componentFunction() {
    const a = aInComponentState;
    console.log(`before: ${a}`);
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(`after: ${a}`);
    }, 1000);
}

componentFunction(); // component function called for mount
++aInComponentState; // button click updates state
componentFunction(); // component function called again because of state update
```

You could return a function from your `useEffect` callback so it knows that the component has been re-rendered between steps 2 and 3 above.

The real solution will vary a fair bit based on what you actually want to do. But if you want `func` to always see the then-current value of `prjToFetch`, and you want both `func` instances to run, you need to use the `setPrjToFetch` setter to access the current value (which is a bit hacky):

```
setPrjToFetch(currentPrjToFetch => {
    console.log("After: " + currentPrjToFetch);
});
```

Again, that's a bit hacky, and usually there are better solutions that are more specific to what you're actually using `prjToFetch` for.

---

I suggest reading [A Complete Guide to `useEffect`](https://amiiy.github.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) by Dan Abramov. It helps you understand `useEffect`, but also hooks in general.